# create array from class in swift

Tags: swift, xcode7

I can't seem to create an array that contains an user. 
I have to create and array of 10 users..
How do I properly create it?

```
import UIKit

enum DeviceType {
    case Phone, Tablet, Watch
}

enum OperatingSystemType {
    case iOS, Android, Windows
}

struct OperatingSystemVersion {
    var Major: Int
    var Minor: Int
    var Patch: Int
}

struct OperatingSystem{
    var type: OperatingSystemType
    var version: OperatingSystemVersion

}

class Device {
    var DeviceID: Int
    var Type: DeviceType
    var Operating_System: OperatingSystem
    var UserID: Int
    var Description: String
    var InventoryNR: String
    init () {
        DeviceID = 1233
        Type = .Phone
        Operating_System = OperatingSystem(type: .iOS, version: OperatingSystemVersion(Major: 9, Minor: 0, Patch: 2))
        UserID = 2
        Description = "took"
        InventoryNR = "no17"
    }
}

class User {
    var UserID: Int
    var Username: String
    var Location: String
    var Devices: [Device]
    init() {
        UserID = 566
        Username = "david"
        Location = "Fortech"
        Devices = [Device.init()]
    }
}

var Users = [User] ()
Users.append(UserID: 23, Username: "David", Location: "HQ", Devices : User)
```

Comment: You need to first create `User`s and then you can append that `User`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a valid initializer for your `User` class (and for the other classes too but we're focusing on `User` here as an example).

```
class User {
    var UserID: Int
    var Username: String
    var Location: String
    var Devices: [Device]
    init(userID: Int, username: String, location: String, devices: [Device]) {
        self.UserID = userID
        self.Username = username
        self.Location = location
        self.Devices = devices
    }
}
```

Now you can create a user:

```
let david = User(userID: 23, username: "David", location: "HQ", devices : [Device()])
```

And add it to your `Users` array:

```
Users.append(david)
```

*Note: class names begin with uppercase letter but variables should begin with a lowercase letter. So your `var UserID: Int` should be `var userID: Int` for example, the `Users` array should be `users`, etc.*

Comment: It was working but it was always initializing an User object with the same hardcoded values. With my example you can make custom User objects.

Comment: Also method and function names should begin with a lower-case letter. The exception for variable names is that is a variable begins with a well know acronym it can be upper-case.

Comment: Thank you! I'll also change the way I declare variables and classes.

Comment: You're welcome. Just for info, there's a great resource here about good style practices for Swift: https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide

Comment: Great resource indeed! :) 
Thanks, again.